# Flowplayer showing overlay error

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

I am trying to use flow player for click on anchor tag to load an overlay video player. It's giving me a type error that overlay is not a function. I tried all possible version but still problem persists. My html code is like below

```
<a href="videos/myvideo.webm" title="my video" class="video" rel="video0"><img id="clip0" src="images/icons/playClip.png"/></a>
<a href="videos/myvideo1.webm" title="my video1" class="video1" rel="video1"><img id="clip1" src="images/icons/playClip.png"/></a>

        <div id="overlay">
            <a class="close"></a>
            <div id="player">&nbsp;</div>
        </div> <!-- this is my div to where i want a modal window type video popup -->
```

My javascript is as below

```
$(function () {
var player = flowplayer("player", "js/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf"); 

$("a[rel]").overlay({
    mask: {
    color: '#000',
    opacity: 0.2
    },
    onLoad: function () {
    player.play(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
    },
    onClose: function () {
    player.unload();
    }
});
```

});

Can any one help with the solution?

```
TypeError: $(...).overlay is not a function
onClose: function () {
```

Comment: do you have jquery tools library included in the page

Comment: @Arun P Johnny Yes I do

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I'm struggling with it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor syntax:

```
$f("a[rel]", "js/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
    // invoked when player loads (not a clip specific event)
    onLoad: function () {
        player.play(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
    },

    onClose: function() {
        player.unload();
    }
});
```

Or the jQuery syntax:

```
 $("a[rel]").flowplayer("js/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", 
    {
    // invoked when player loads (not a clip specific event)
    onLoad: function () {
        player.play(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        },

    onClose: function() {
        player.unload();
        } 
  })
```

**References**

- [FlowPlayer: Flash JavaScript API](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/api/flowplayer.html)